# How to count number of missing values for each column of a data frame in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I want to know count number of missing values for each column of a data frame in spark scala.

Example output,

fileheader: col1missigcount:2, col2misscount:1, col3misscount:2

My Code

```
val samplesqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM sampletable")

samplesqlDF.show()
```

sample table data:

```
   |----------------------------------------------------------------|
   | name       |     age             |  degree                     |
   | ---------------------------------------------------------------|
   | ram        |                     |    MCA                      |
   |            |     25              |                             |
   |            |     26              |     BE                      |
   | Suganya    |     24              |                             |
   -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `df.columns` to get columns in a data-frame and then use dataframe functions like `col()`, `agg()`, `sum()`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

scala> val df = Seq(("ram"," ","MCA"),("","25",""),("","26","BE"),("Suganya","24","")).toDF("name","age","degree")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, age: string ... 1 more field]


// You can get all columns names in an array
scala> df.columns
res12: Array[String] = Array(name, age, degree)

// Now map through all column names creating an sum-expression for each column.
scala> val aggCols = df.columns.map(colName => 
                              // Create a sum column, with conditions as per your requirement.
                              sum(when(col(colName).isNull 
                                         || col(colName) === "" 
                                         || col(colName) === " ",1).otherwise(0)
                              // Alias each column by appending "_c"
                                  ).as(colName + "_c"))
aggCols: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = Array(sum(CASE WHEN (((name IS NULL) OR (name = )) OR (name =  )) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `name_c`, sum(CASE WHEN (((age IS NULL) OR (age = )) OR (age =  )) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `age_c`, sum(CASE WHEN (((degree IS NULL) OR (degree = )) OR (degree =  )) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `degree_c`)

// Use agg function and apply the array of sum-expressions. 
scala> df.agg(aggCols.head, aggCols.tail: _*).show
+------+-----+--------+
|name_c|age_c|degree_c|
+------+-----+--------+
|     2|    1|       2|
+------+-----+--------+
```

You may also look at `df.schema` this has more meta-data than `df.column`.

```
scala> df.schema
res14: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(name,StringType,true), StructField(age,StringType,true), StructField(degree,StringType,true))
```

Comment: Its Working. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

If you are not casting the blanks to nulls for string columns, then the below works

```
scala> val df = Seq(("ram"," ","MCA"),("","25",""),("","26","BE"),("Suganya","24","")).toDF("name","age","degree")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, age: string ... 1 more field]

scala> val df2 = df.withColumn("age",'age.cast("int"))
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, age: int ... 1 more field]

scala> df2.show
+-------+----+------+
|   name| age|degree|
+-------+----+------+
|    ram|null|   MCA|
|       |  25|      |
|       |  26|    BE|
|Suganya|  24|      |
+-------+----+------+


scala> df2.agg(sum(when('age.isNull,1).otherwise(0)).as("agec"), sum(when('name==="",1).otherwise(0)).as("namec"),sum(when('degree==="",1).otherwise(0)).as("degreec")).show
+----+-----+-------+
|agec|namec|degreec|
+----+-----+-------+
|   1|    2|      2|
+----+-----+-------+


scala>
```

Comment: My table can contain any number of columns. example purpose I gave 3 columns. i want output like this [fileheader: col1missigcount:2, col2misscount:1, col3misscount:2]

Comment: in that case, you can extend the agg function, by adding as many column as you have in the csv.

Comment: I am not sure how many columns I am going to check the count. it should increase dynamically.I don't want to extend the column names manually.

Comment: in that case, you need to write meta-programming by grabbing the csv header and  create the scala code as in this answer

Comment: @revathi-k, What is the fileheader in your output. Is it the name of `csv` file containing the data?

Comment: @stack0114106 Moreover the dataframe my contain other data types such as dates etc. and can be more involved. I think the attempt by you is fairly good. If you can, you may try by grabbing column names into an `Array` using `df2.columns` or may be using `df2.schema` . I don't have exact idea. But I am interested  to know how it can be done.

Comment: @RAGHHURAAMM yes, this is generic handling of csv. You need 2 pass compilation for processing it. In the first pass, use meta-programming and construct the code that will be used in the second pass. will give a try